# executing code of a webapp from mutiple tenants within a single process

Tags: http, web, process, multi-tenant

Can you explain multi tenancy in more detail? how to check whether that is working or not?
What is a http adaptor? Can we create two http adaptors in a single process?Correct me if I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To give you a brief overview of multi tenant concepts may run through several pages. IMHO, the concept of multi tenancy for a developer can be mentioned as,
Single code base or multiple code bases (Based on the level of multi-tenancy) set up in a server or in a server farm to cater to all the disparate tenant's that may have varying user experience, varying applications (managed through subscription) and each tenant given a feel of dedicated application by showing them their own data and the corresponding bills for what features of the app they are using.

If you maintain a single code base, it is complicated in terms of development and a piece of cake when it comes to upgrade or bug fix etc...

You should Google around for multi-tenancy. The sample link is :http://blogs.gartner.com/alessandro-perilli/multitenancy-is-not-just-network-isolation-and-rbac/

Please fell free to post your specific focus area in multi-tenancy and technology that you are opting for so the community help will be to the grain.